# How to extend jQuery UI effect

Tags: jquery

I have this effect  `$("#stage").effect("pulsate", { times: 1 }, 700);`

But there are no configuration settings that I can use.
For example the Pulsate effect will bring the opacity down to 0% and then back up to 100%.
What can be done so that the opacity will go down to 70% instead of 0%?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The API does not specify any way to do it.
I would recommend using [animate()](http://api.jquery.com/animate/) to do the single pulse.
**Remember that animations are queued**, so you could do like this:

```
$("#stage").animate({opacity : 0.7}).animate({opacity : 1})
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$('#stage').animate({opacity: 0.70});
```

Set an interval if necessary to make it pulsate.